# Using <mvc:resources .../> in spring 3 causes all other views to stop working

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Simplest example:

I have a dispatcher servlet configured to catch everything:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have a simple test controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/index")
@ResponseBody
public String rootTest(){
    return "Main page displayed from TestController";
}
```

In this test case I am adding (or removing) the following line to `dispatcher-servlet.xml`:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/public/**" location="/public/"/>
```

**My lofty goal:** to serve static content (images, css, js) along with my dynamic content (generated via Velocity within a Jetty servlet container, tied together with the almighty Spring).

**My Dilema:** When I add `<mvc:resources .../>` I get a 404 for `http://localhost/index`, but I can serve an image from http://localhost/public/img/42.png. If I remove `<mvc:resources .../>` then `http://localhost/index` works fine, but of course, how do I serve static content?

**Bonus question:** Why can I never have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

There are 2 problems:

1. Never use `/*` in servlet mapping:

   ```
   <servlet-mapping> 
       <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name> 
       <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
   </servlet-mapping>
   ```
2. `<mvc:resources>` requires `<mvc:annotation-driven>` (or explicitly declared handler mappings, etc).

   This happens because `DispatcherServlet` applies default configuration of handler mappings only when no custom handler mappings found in the context. Since `<mvc:resources>` adds its own handler mapping, defaults are broken, therefore other handler mappings should be decalred explicitly, either by `<mvc:annotation-driven>` or manually as beans.

   Also note that `<mvc:resources>` declares only `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping` and doesn't declare other mappings such as `BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping`, though they are in defaults of `DispatcherServlet`. Declare them manually if you need them.

Comment: Thanks very much! Question though (I'm new with spring), I had (in an attempt to follow the docs) added <context:component-scan base-package="com.mydomain.web"/> to scan the controllers, does mvc:annotation-driven replace that? I'm a little fuzzy between the "easy new way to do things" vs. "doing things the old way", seems that there is 3 ways to do everything in Spring and sometimes I think I mix them.

Comment: @David: `<mvc:annotation-driven>` doesn't replace `<context:component-scan>`, it just configures new features of Spring MVC (perhaps it's poorly named).

Comment: Thanks, I did what you said and the magic happened, I now have a real honest-to-goodness webapp. :)

Comment: @axtavt i had problems rendering jsps using /* in the servlet mapping. Requests to /WEB-INF/folder/jspfile.jsp went through DispatcherServlet and i had to use mvc:default-servlet-handler. Even then jsp includes failed, as jsp requests are forwarded (instead of included) by default in the DefaultHttpServletRequestHandler. Switching the mapping to / helped me avoid this problem. What exactly is the difference between / and /* mapping?

Comment: @axtavt Can you elaborate a bit what's wrong with the `/*` mapping? And why making the servlet the default servlet is important?

Answer (score 0):

I also met this problem before. My situation was **I didn't put all the 62 spring framework jars into the lib file** (spring-framework-4.1.2.RELEASE edition), it did work. And then I also changed the 3.0.xsd into 2.5 or 3.1 for test, it all worked out. Of course, there are also other factors to affect your result.

Answer (score -3):

add "mvc:annotation-driven" line into view resolvers SpringWeb.XML file. it is work for me