# SpringMVC RequestMapping for GET url parameters

Tags: java, spring-mvc

How to make the RequestMapping to handle GET parameters in the url? For example i have this url

localhost:8080/MyApplication/spm/gcNkyLXkwv

how to get the spm value from the above url

Comment: Possible duplicate of [With Spring 3.0, can I make an optional path variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4904092/with-spring-3-0-can-i-make-an-optional-path-variable)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using PathVariable. I will just give example how it can be done. You can incorporate in your example

Suppose you want to write a url to fetch some order, you can say

```
www.mydomain.com/order/123
```

where `123` is orderId.

So now the url you will use in spring mvc controller would look like

/order/{orderId}
Now order id can be declared a path variable

```
@RequestMapping(value = " /order/{orderId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getOrder(@PathVariable String orderId){
//fetch order
}
```

if you use url `www.mydomain.com/order/123`, then `orderId` variable will be populated by value 123 by spring

Also note that PathVariable differ from requestParam as pathVariable are part of URL. The same url using request param would look like  `www.mydomain.com/order?orderId=123`

Comment: Hi, its working perfectly.Thank you for your valuable suggestion. But some issues occurred while populating the result view.The JavaScript file and all other css files are not taken.The path for the JavaScript and css files are shown as                                                                                                         networkError: 404 Not Found - localhost:8080/MyApplication/spm/css/style.css".                 The original path is MyApplication/css/style.css .How to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you running application using IDE?

Comment: Yes using eclipse with spring MVC

Comment: I had many times the problem, didn't find solution for that. Hence I m running all the things manually rather than running in IDE. You can raise new issue for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11952212/spring-3-1-javascript-file-not-found-404-error This may help you.

Comment: And this too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18373165/spring-mvcresources-tag-and-404-error