# Spring MVC 4.1.7 WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/user] in DispatcherServlet

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, controller, annotations

I am trying to link to an annotation defined Java controller RequestMapping. Specifically, localhost:8080/user and localhost:8080/signin

The index page loads just fine, but that's not due to the controller. I must be missing something silly. I've been all up and down stack overflow looking for solutions, but so far nothing has worked.

The most popular answers for this warning seem to be adding context:component-scan, mvc:annotation-driven, or even just naming issues. It seems I have all the configuration in xml necessary, and then some. Am I missing something about project structure? Or url pattern matching? Someone mentioned jstl and adding c:tags for urls, but that didn't work either.

I'm trying to run all the latest, maybe there's an issue? I had trouble initially setting up the environment to work with webapp 3.1. Most of the configuration happened automatically with spring sts tool.

- Java 8
- Tomcat 8
- Web App 3.1
- Maven 4.0
- STS 3.7.0

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
                         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>AppName</name>
<description>App Desc</description>

<!-- custom properties -->
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.1.7.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- j2ee -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>InstagramPUE</finalName>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     id="igpue" version="3.1">

<!-- app config -->
<display-name>App Display Name</display-name>
<description>App Desc</description>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- app context -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- servlet config -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/signin</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.txt</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd"> 

<!-- mvc config -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />
<mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/resources/**" />

<!-- scan for controller -->
<context:component-scan base-package="abnd.igpue.controller" />

<!-- bean config -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" />
    <link href="<c:url value='/resources/css/style.css' />" rel="stylehseet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <!-- html -->
    <div id="page">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="title"><span>Title</span></div>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <div id="signIn">
                <c:url value="/signin" var="signInLink" />
                <div id="signInLink"><a href="${signInLink}">Sign in to Instagram</a></div>
                <c:url value="/user" var="userLink" />
                <div id="userpage"><a href="${userLink}">User Page</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- js -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**User.java**

```
package abnd.igpue.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller 
public class User {

@RequestMapping(value = "/signin")
public String signIn() {  

    // if the signin was successful redirect to user page

    return "redirect:user";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/user")  
public ModelAndView userHome() {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("/jsp/user.jsp");
    mav.setViewName("User");

    String message = "<br><div>"
            + "<h1>Hello World</h1></div><br><br>";

    mav.addObject("message", message);

    return mav;
}
}
```

Comment: Turn on your INFO logs for Spring and check which handler methods are registered and for which paths.

Comment: Why three url-patterns in servlet mapping? You could've just given <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> the rest patterns will be covered under this. Is your signIn mapping working fine?

Comment: If you remove <url-pattern>/signin</url-pattern> and <url-pattern>/user</url-pattern> does your code work? Before migrating to java config i used to set mine to "<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>" only and let the code do the rest

Comment: I think if you are specifying the component-scan, you should not specify the servlet-mapping in the xml.

Comment: @Aeseir i tried this, but the only thing that happens is my welcome page doesn't load anymore, then I try to load it with the controller, but the controller is never stepped into. I will continue trying something like this though.

Comment: @underdog using /, or /* doesn't seem to do much. I think the signin mapping is fine, the controller is never stepped into though, so I guess maybe not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten it working. I scrapped the code I had, and completely rebuilt it from the ground up. I found a few issues in my last project between these two stack overflow posts (below), but even after getting the new project to work, I could not successfuly update the code I was positing about originally. There must be something silly I was missing.

**Resources**

A post here details how 
[Using <mvc:resources .../> in spring 3 causes all other views to stop working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057529/using-mvcresources-in-spring-3-causes-all-other-views-to-stop-working)
Another post here details how to  [Add css in spring mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537863/add-css-in-spring-mvc/20539934#20539934)

**I have uploaded a starter Spring Web MVC Project to my github!**

If anyone is interested, here ya go. You can download and import as maven project. https://github.com/BorysHN/SpringMVCSkeleton