# How to make static images visible in Spring MVC application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources

I am unable to make static images visible in Spring MVC application.

If I add

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

into `dispatcher-servlet.xml` or `applicationContext.xml` then I am loosing an ability to execute controllers.

My current `dispatcher-servlet.xml` is follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.inthemoon.snippets.springmvc" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When I am opening `/hello` URL I am getting an error in log:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'
```

If I remove `resources` directive, I see the following messages in the log:

```
04-Dec-2015 22:30:15.687 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]
04-Dec-2015 22:30:16.012 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/hello] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
04-Dec-2015 22:30:16.013 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/hello.*] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
04-Dec-2015 22:30:16.013 INFO [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping.registerHandler Mapped URL path [/hello/] onto handler 'helloWorldController'
```

These messages are absent if `resources` directive is present.

Comment: are you using maven?

Answer (score 0):

You have to insert `<mvc:annotation-driven>` if you want to use the `<mvc:resources ...>` statement.

See for more details the following question & answer: [Using mvc:resources problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4057529/using-mvcresources-in-spring-3-causes-all-other-views-to-stop-working)

Comment: If you have further troubles, maybe you need the following statement aswell: `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />`.

Comment: Actually, I don't want to use `resources` I want to display images in the most convenient way.

Comment: Well, I think `mvc:resources` is not a bad way to provide the access to your static resources including images. What exactly do you mean with "make visible"? Accessing them in one of your sites is after using the mvc-directive easy by using `<img src="/images/picture...." />`. Sorry if I misunterstood you.